# Call the same view "N" times in ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, tableview

I hope that you can give me an advice about my problem:
    I have a view controller associate to a class.
    I'm trying to use the same viewcontroller to show different information.. 'n' times 
    My view contains: imageview and table (in the table gonna show the results) 
   Why the same? ---> Because is the same structure: name and image

Example:
  1-- Subcategory: Clothes, Shoes
  2-- If you selected "Clothes" It shows: Dresses, Jeans, Blouses.
  3-- If you selected "Dresses" It shows: Evening dresses, short dresses, etc
  I dont know when It goes stop, because it depends if the subcategory selected has more elements to show.
  I control it, when the view hasn't elements to show, I send other view, that's no my problem.

Which the problem? -- The problem is that I'm calling the same view and my array keeps the last value received, 
  If I want to back (because I use navigation controller), I can't select other value.

Based on the previos example:
   - I selected "Clothes" (It has 3 results)
   - And now I going to back and I want Selected "Shoes"
   Appears :
   '*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1)'' en Getting Started

This happens because my last array had 3 item, and the Cell that I pressed has 2.

```
// ---------MY CODE IS:
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cat, *nom;
    cat = AId[indexPath.row];
    nom = ACateg[indexPath.row];
    [self wsCategorias: @"0" dato2: cat];

    if(existe == FALSE ){
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(cargando:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
        // ------ my process
    }
    else {
        /************************************** CALLING THE SAME VIEW ****************/

        Subcategoria1 *sub = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Sub1"];
        sub.idCat = cat;
        sub.nomCat = nom;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:sub animated:YES];
    }
}
```

How I can use the same view but each view keep the correct value?? would have to create new views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you're trying to do is push and pop view controllers that look the same, but contain different data and an array with different values inside of it.

What you need to do, depending on how you setup your view controller, is to instantiate a new one every time you want to push to a new section.

- If you are using Storyboards you can give the view controller an identifier and instantiate it programmatically.
- If you are using NIBs, then you can initialize the controller from the NIB.
- If you are instantiating your controller programmatically, then simply write the code to alloc/init it, and you'll have a new controller.

Regardless of who you instantiate your view controller, you want a new one for every subcategory you select.

For example, let's say you are going from the main list which shows

- Jeans
- Dresses
- Shoes
- Accessories

And then you select Jeans and want to show its subitems which could be:

- Adult Jeans
- Kids Jeans

What you would do is instantiate a new view controller, pass in the subitems array data (which in this example contains 'Adult Jeans' and 'Kids Jeans'), and push it onto your navigation stack. That way, when you tap the back button, iOS will automatically go back to where you were, and you can reuse the same view controller and UI endlessly as you need.

Comment: Thanks for the response , So,  Have I to create a new controller? , Can use the same identifier ? Only call the view but passing the subitems array data..?
  I'll do that you comment , thanks so much!!!

Comment: It depends on how you have setup your view controller. Are you using storyboards to create your view controller, a .xib file, or via code? 

Depending on that, how you instantiate it will change but the end result will be the same; A view controller ready for you to present and have it populate with your own data.

Comment: I'm using storyboard,

Comment: But I do this:  Subcategoria1 *sub = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Sub1"];
        sub.idCat = cat;
        sub.nomCat = nom;

You refered this?

Comment: Yes, so if you gave the view controller the identifier of "Sub1" in your Storyboard, and you instantiate it, you can now setup an array in the .h file that you use to pass in the data it needs to populate the table, and then push it onto the navigation controller's view stack.

Comment: ok, actually, I don't know if I declared in the incorrect place my array, in my code, is in .m , and then I fill it in the ws, when I instatiated my story board, i send two values, but I don't setup the array because when Icalled the "wsCategorias"  , there have de value... Can you understand me? .. maybe this form is incorrect, but I want know why. In my ws i do this:  AId=jsonData[@"ID"];
                ACateg=jsonData[@"Categorias"];

Comment: You will probably have to move your array or data structure/model to the .h file, so you can pass it in to the view controller when you instantiate it from the storyboard. Otherwise, there is no way for you to set the data you need in the new view controller instance.

Comment: sorry, sorry, I had already done that.. but what am I missing??  mi code is the same as above